# Can`t change the height on a image in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, dom

I want to create a function for for my header when its changing his size.
I have a logo img inside the header.I want when i change the header`s height to be for example 80px the image to be 80 px as well.
I initialized a function in Javascript but doesn`t work( i`m a beginner at Javascript). Please tell me what i m doing wrong in js and maybe show me the right way to do it.

```
 <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header-content">
       <img src='http://www.lazarangelov.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/logo1.jpg' class="logo" alt="logo">
        <div class="menu-links">
          <ul class="links-list">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Academy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>


.header {
    background: blue;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 20;
  height: 80px;}
.header-content{
  display:flex;
}
.menu-links{
  display:flex;
}
.links-list{
  display:flex;
  color:white;
}


const mainNav = document.querySelector('.header');
const img = document.querySelector('.logo');

if (mainNav.style.height == '80px') {
    img.style.height = '80px';
} else {
    img.style.height = '100px';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.style` property can only return style information that has been set directly into the HTML element, either statically in the HTML as in: `<p style="something here">` or via the `.style` being set in JavaScript as in: `element.style = something;`. Your code is based on an `if` condition that checks `mainNav.style.height`, but the `style` property hasn't been set in HTML or JavaScript at that point.

Instead, use [`.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), which returns the final value for the provided style after all computations (regardless of where they were applied) are taken into account.

I've added a red border to your image in the code below to show that it is expanding the `height` to be the same size as the `header`.

```js
const mainNav = document.querySelector('.header');
const img = document.querySelector('.logo');

// You can't check the .style property if the element
// hasn't had that attribute or property set yet.
if (getComputedStyle(mainNav).height == '80px') {
    img.style.height = '80px';
} else {
    img.style.height = '100px';
}
```

```css
.logo { border:1px dashed red; }
.header {
    background: blue;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 20;
  height: 80px;}
.header-content{
  display:flex;
}
.menu-links{
  display:flex;
}
.links-list {
  display:flex;
  color:white;
}

.links-list a { color: white; }
```

```html
<header class="header">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="header-content">
   <img src=
'http://www.lazarangelov.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/logo1.jpg'
     class="logo" alt="logo">
        <div class="menu-links">
          <ul class="links-list">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Academy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: Man... i don`t have words to thank you for your answer...was everything that i was looking for 2 days.

Comment: @DConstantin Glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The [style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property in Javascript only gives you the element's *inline* styles - those defined directly in a `style` attribute on it.

You need [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to access the actual properties used, taking into account all CSS rules.